# How to post a audio file to facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am developing an application to post an audio file to facebook. Can any body tell me what I should do to be able to post an audio to face book using my application.

Thanx....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I got the answer. You can post audio to facebook using you iPhone application with type=mp3 not the type=music(as mentioned in Facebook documentation). Just make your param dictionary and send it with request object to facebook and you are done.

Comment: @iOS Monster-Can u give me Example?

Answer (score 2):

you are able to upload photos or videos, but no audio files.
see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

you should upload your file to a separate server an publish a link to the resulting url on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can post only MP3s through the API as mentioned above.  If you want to post WAV files for use in podcast and such you can only post a link or use an iphone/android app to do the work for you like microcast chipbit or something like that.